# Exponential inequality problem

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, inequality

How to solve this inequality $e^{(x-2)}>\frac{1}{x-2}$ ?

I tried to plot graph and able to get some bound as answer but not satisfy with the approach ?

Anyhow we can convert this problem by substitution that $e^{x}>\frac{1}{x}$

Some help needed?

Comment: Substitute $t = x-2$, is that what you need?

Comment: @peter.petrov how to proceed after that ?

Comment: Use the Lambert function.

Comment: Well, depends on what you know already i.e. what you have as knowledge previously taught to you. You need some elementary method?

Comment: Yes @peter.petrov I am not aware of Lambert function and higher stuff may be calculus method are good enough

Comment: Do you know derivatives and that if derivative $f' > 0$ the function $f$ is increasing? I mean, can you use this in your solution?

Comment: I think only problem is for (0,1) ? @peter.petrov for $e^x$ case

Comment: @peter you can use derivative?

Comment: I can, the question is can you use it in your solution :)

Comment: Yes @peter I understand derivative concept.

Answer (score 0):

Let $t=x-2$, we have:
$$e^t>\frac{1}{t}$$
The solution is:
$$t<0 \vee t>W(1)\approx 0.567143$$
where $W(z)$ is the product log function. Substituing agian, we have:
$$x<2 \vee x>W(1)+2\approx 2.567143$$

Comment: Why it is greater than W(1) can you explain that ?

Comment: I read the basic of Lambert function it is inverse of $xe^x$ can somebody explain with this reagard?

Comment: @mathsstudent: $x>W(1)+2\approx 2.567143$ because from $x=W(1)+2\approx 2.567143$ the unction $e^x-\frac{1}{x}$ is increasing and always positive. Also, see here for explaination about solving exponential equation with $W(z)$.

Comment: You have not added any link

Comment: @mathsstudent: yes, sorry. See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function and here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GKdEbFO-5lY

Comment: Can you explain why $t>W(1)$ this is true?

Comment: What I get is $e^t t  > 1$ then how to proceed to conclude above abound?